# RDP From Windows 8.1 To Virtualbox Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: virtualbox, 15.04, remote, rdp, xrdp

Well I have been on to this problem for quite some time now. I've been trying to search for legit answers, but everytime I do, it doesn't seem to work out for me. Mostly, the answers I get is from Ubuntu 14.04, which I'm not sure would work the same with 15.04

I have Ubuntu 15.04 installed on my VirtualBox. Another problem i'm encountering is that when I select `"Bridged Adapter"` as my network adapter, it won't connect me to the internet. So basically what i'm saying is that I can't do updates and installs when using  `Bridged Adapter`. I have to switch it to NAT in order to do so.

Now back to the problem, i've found few answers which I thought would work well. I've installed `xrdp` and `vino`. I've enabled `remote display`. I've tried editing `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`. But everytime I tried to connect to the network using the right IP address, it just prompts `error - problem connecting`.

Here are the video links i've tried, but still won't get it to go.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFdBSyy4xcM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1ay7toiJ6k

I hope someone could help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should configure port forwarding in Virtualbox:

- Open Virtualbox and open the settings dialog for your virtual machine
- Choose "Network" -> Advanced -> Port Forwarding
- Add a new rule with the "+" button on the right
- Enter a new rule name "RDP"
- Protocol = TCP
- Host IP = 127.0.0.1
- Host Port = 3389 (for the port number: see this [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/de-de/windows7/allow-remote-desktop-connections-from-outside-your-home-network), "Forward TCP port...")
- Guest Port = 3389
- Leave the Guest IP addresses empty
- Confirm everything
- Restart the vm

This means: forward all tcp traffic coming into host port 3389 to the guest (vm machine port) 3389.

Comment: VirutalBox does not allow me to leave the Guest IP empty

Comment: This solution doesn't work unfortunately.  At least, it is not an accurate answer to the op's question in all cases, since I experience the same problem as op and this solution doesn't offer any help.